# how to add permissions with samba

Tags: windows, ubuntu, samba

i have a samba file server on ubuntu server for my windows pc and when i try to write on the shared drive it says that i need permission to do that. i have done this:

```
sudo chown nobody:nogroup /var/www/html
```

and my smb.conf is:

```
[webpage]
    comment = Ubuntu File Server Share
    path = /var/www/html
    browsable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    read only = no
    create mask = 0755
```

i have another shared folder and that one is working fine with the same .conf
please can somebody tell me how to give myself permissions. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection probably doesn't run as the user you think it does.

- You can try to find out as with user samba runs that connection. Run

  ```
  chmod 1777 /var/www/html
  ```

  Then you should be able to create a file in that directory. It will have the user and group of the Samba process for this connection.

  Change the permissions back after that.
- You can change the user and group of the Samba process with these lines in `smb.conf`

  ```
  force user = nobody
  force group = nogroup
  ```